Most tag tooltips do not appear anymore
Steps to reproduce:

Visit stackoverflow.com/questions
Hover your mouse over one of the tags of any question in the list other than the question which appears first (at the top of the list.)

Expected result:
A tooltip for the tag should appear.
Actual result:
No tooltip appears.
Remarks:
The tooltip does appear if you hover over the tags of the first question in the list. (Duh!?)
Happens with Mozilla Firefox and with Microsoft Edge.
Happens regardless of whether I am logged in or not.

For me, I see a problem even on the first instance of the tag. More specifically, it's shifted down a lot: https://i.sstatic.net/UD6P9PbE.png If I hover over a tag on the second question, I can barely see it https://i.sstatic.net/kpiUhmb8.png FF 130 on Windows 10

If I zoom out a bunch I can see the tag tooltip for a few more questions but they show up quite far below the actual place where the tag is.

@VLAZ you are right, that's in fact what is happening.

OK, not quite as clear cut. The popup location seems to be different. Depends on where the viewport is. Some times it shows the popup for the tags of the first question where it should, other times, it's a little bit off, other times very far off. And for question #2 and more, the tooltip seems to be even further down usually. I'm not even sure how I got it to show in the viewport in my first screenshot.

Seems like an issue with all SE sites (Not just SO which has an ongoing experiment for the tag tooltip), I can reproduce on other sites as well.

Also happens on the actual question pages. Whatever calculation is used to show the tooltip it seems to be way off. Here is a very zoomed out page of a question - if I am on the top of it (scrolled all the way up), then the tooltip doesn't show. If I scroll down, it now shows on a position I should have seen it before

For me, the tooltips appear on hover for the first two questions, but not on the rest, Chrome on Windows.  For questions, the tooltips will show up near the bottom of the screen if I scroll down so the tags are present in the top ~20% of the screen (of the physical viewport, including browser chrome and sticky top bar); if they're below a certain place vertically on the screen the tooltips don't appear. Very strange.

Happens also in the Staging Ground (FF129 + Win10). Tooltips for the 1st Row/Qt only appear at 80% Zoom-level, 2nd Row at 67% Zoom, first 5 Rows at 50% Zoom with 16 Rows visible on the screen...

I cannot reproduce this anymore (Windows 11/Firefox), but it was happening to me a few hours ago. Tried different zoom levels, window sizes, other sites; all work. Might have been fixed?

Yep, seems to be fixed.

For me it started working again after clearing temporary cached files and pages (Firefox 130.0, Win 10).
